# Unit/integration testing EF with Effort - Connectionstring not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, effort

I recently started using the in-memory database Effort to unit test my entity framework implementations.

Everything works well, except when I try to load data from a CSV file into the database using the CSV dataloader.

Documentation on exactly how to configure the csvdataloader seems to be scarce / insufficient.

Here is one of the NUnit 3.0 unit tests I have written:

```
    [Test]
    public void GetBudgetIncomeItems_MultipleValidItems_ReturnList()
    {
        //Prepare and load data
        var dataLoader = new CsvDataLoader(@"<DirectoryOfUnitTestProject>\Data");
        var entityConnection = Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreateTransient("name=<NameOfMyCSVFileWithoutCSVExtension/DatabaseName>", dataLoader);
        _serviceContext = new ServiceContext(entityConnection);

        //Execute test
        var items = _query.GetBudgetIncomeItems(new Application {Id = 3});

        //Check results
        //Some assertions
    }
```

An exception is thrown on the line:

```
Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreateTransient("name=<NameOfMyCSVFileWithoutCSVExtension/DatabaseName>", dataLoader);
```

Exception detail:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147024809   Message=Connectionstring was not found Parameter
>   name: entityConnectionString   ParamName=entityConnectionString
>   Source=Effort   StackTrace:
>          at Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.GetFullEntityConnectionString(String
>   entityConnectionString)
>          at Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.GetEffortCompatibleMetadataWorkspace(String&
>   entityConnectionString)
>          at Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreateTransient(String entityConnectionString, IDataLoader dataLoader)
>          at Infrastructure.EF6.UnitTests.PacsQueryTests`1.GetBudgetIncomeItems_MultipleValidItems_ReturnList()
>   in
>   \PacsQueryTests.cs:line
>   36   InnerException:

Any help would be appreciated...

### Update

As per comments from @Evk below, when using Code first, you have to make use of the DbConnection and DbConnectionFactory classes, and not the EntityConnection and EntityConnectionFactory classes.

My updated code, which does not throw any errors, looks as follows:

```
        [Test]
        public void GetBudgetIncomeItems_MultipleValidItems_ReturnList()
        {
            //Prepare and load data
            Effort.DataLoaders.IDataLoader csvDataLoader = new Effort.DataLoaders.CsvDataLoader(@"<DirectoryOfUnitTestProject>\Data");
            var dataLoader = new Effort.DataLoaders.CachingDataLoader(csvDataLoader,false);
            DbConnection dbConnection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient(dataLoader);
            _serviceContext = new ServiceContext(dbConnection);

            //Execute test
            var items = _query.GetBudgetIncomeItems(new Application {Id = 3});

            //Check results
            //Some assertions
        }
```

Comment: You need to provide valid Entity Framework connection string there (with "metadata" element and so on).

Comment: @Evk Thanks, but not sure I follow... could you perhaps provide an example or references?

Comment: @Evk I notmally define connectionstrings in app.config/web.config targeted at sql server.  Not sure how this connection string should be formatted...

Comment: Well how do you normally connect to your database with Entity Framework? You have some connection string somewhere (could be in app.config\web.config), and it's in proper format (`metadata=res://*/TestDbModel.csdl|res://*/TestDbModel.ssdl|res://*/TestDbModel.msl;` and so on). You need to use such string here, directly (without refering to it by name). Though I've only used Effort with database-first model, not sure if it's the same for code-first (as you said - documentation is not quite good).

Comment: @Evk I understand that, but I am unfamiliar with the way in which the connection string is formatted in your example.  Sorry if this is a stupid question, but trying to understand how that connection string is formulated. I use code first exclusively... I think perhaps your string is only relevant to model/database first, since we do not have these types of metadata files being generated in code first?

Comment: You are right, I've only used Effort with database-first. What I would suggest in your case is not create EntityConnection, but instead DbConnection, like this: `DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient(dataLoader)`. Then pass that connection to context constructor. If your context does not have constructor which accepts such connection - create one (because DbContext does support using DbConnection).

Comment: @Evk Yes, that is exactly what I have done now (immediately started after my last comment).  It seems to have worked, since I am not getting the same error anymore.  However, it seems that data from my csv is not being loaded into the database, even though I have the exact columns in my CSV as on my entity, and have given the csv file the same name as my table.  I will post my code as an update to my question.

Comment: what should be the connection string in case of Code First

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to this party but their is one post that seems to answer the question.  I spent half a day looking for it.  Hopefully posting it here will spread the word.

https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Effort/issues/99

Credit goes to the author of the original post above.

```
EntityFrameworkEffortManager.ContextFactory = context => new MyContext();
var dataLoader = new EntityDataLoader();
DbConnection dbConnection = DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient(dataLoader);
var effortContext = new MyContext(dbConnection);
```

Comment: Which code above(I see code below)? What is the name of that author?

Comment: The 'above' refers to the post for which I provided the link.  If you follow the instructions in the link you'll have your answer.